# Rewrite Rules OR Redirects using percentage Signs and hyphens

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I attempted to look this up in various forums but couldn't find anything that actually worked for me. I'm trying to redirect or force rewrite rules on a set of URLs that have spaces OR '%20' and essentially break when trying to resolve a redirect. Old site is a statis site to new site which is Wordpress which shouldnt matter.

This is what I have :

```
Redirect 301 http://www.exampledomain.com/pdf/PA%20article%20-%20Cross%20Selling.pdf http://www.exampledomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/PA_article_-_Cross_Selling.pdf
```

Which doesnt work and ends up just going back to the root location. Alternatively, I tried to do a RewriteRule that didn't make any difference either below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^pdf/PA%20article%20-%20Cross%20Selling\.pdf$ /wp-content/uploads/2014/12/PA_article_-_Cross_Selling.pdf?&%{QUERY_STRING} [B,r=301,nc]
```

Cant anyone else look at this and tell what I am doing wrong

Comment: that looks like you are rewriting a perfectly acceptable filename into one with %20 nonsense in it

Comment: @RamRaider, I think you have that backwards...The OP wants to redirect a URI that has spaces in it to one with underscores.

Comment: That's what I would have thought - but the rewrite rule seems backwards to me

Comment: Hey @RamRaider I am assuming it is in the correct order. The Old URL first and the New URL after. rnevius is correct that I want to take the URL with spaces and replace it with the ones without spaces. The .pdf filenames were bad but now they are acceptable.

Comment: This is a snippet from one of my htaccess files that rewrites a dynamic php page as a javascript file - as you can see the order is rewritten then original path.

RewriteRule ^scripts/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.js$ /res/dynamic/core_javascript.php?files=$1&signature=$2&page=$3&key=$4 [NC,L]

Comment: @RamRaider...your code example shows the original first, and then the rewritten. The `$1`, `$2`, etc. are backreferences to the regex match in the original URL.

Answer (score 0):

The following `RewriteRule` uses `\s` to match any whitespace character:

```
RewriteRule ^pdf/PA\sarticle\s-\sCross\sSelling.pdf$ wp-content/uploads/2014/12/PA_article_-_Cross_Selling.pdf
```